# COM in AHK to operate Word. Documents.Activate unpredictable behavior

Tags: vba, ms-word, com, autohotkey

Following code was supposed to activate Document A upon pressing ^a and Document B upon pressing ^b. Both files already exist and are opened. Sometimes both work, sometimes one does and the other does not, sometimes neither work. The error message reads "bad file name". Adding or removing .docx from the file name has no effect. The first execution of the script after restarting the computer tends to work.

OS: Windows 10.

```
^a::
wrdApp := ComObjActive("Word.Application") ; Activate MS Word object
wrdApp.Documents("DocumentA").Activate
wrdApp.Visible := true
return

^b::
wrdApp := ComObjActive("Word.Application") ; Activate MS Word object
wrdApp.Documents("DocumentB").Activate 
wrdApp.Visible := true
return

^w::
wrdApp.Selection.EndKey(wdStory)
wrdApp.Selection.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText("** Here")
return
```

[Error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ0CA.png

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the `.Activate` fails if the doc is already the active doc in the Word instance defined by `wrdApp` and so you will need to test for that condition. See my answer below (which I posted before I noticed you said it sometimes worked).

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I think you need to make the Word instance `.visible` before you can do the `.activate` and for another, making the Doc active does not bring the Window forward. Use `WinActivate` after the other stuff.  Here's how all that would look:

```
^a::
    wrdApp := ComObjActive("Word.Application") ; Activate MS Word object
    wrdApp.Visible := true
    wrdApp.Documents("DocumentA").Activate
    WinActivate DocumentA 
return
```

But importantly, pls note, DocumentA must exist and be open **but not active** when you issue the command. Maybe put in a test for that condition.  But why aren't you just using `WinActivate` anyway?  With all the `WinTitle` options and etc., it would seem the most bullet-proof.

**EDIT**: Since OP said it sometimes works, I conclude my suggestion about the order of the methods is not critical, but rather, probably the doc is already the active one and so the command fails.

Hth,

Comment: Changing the order .visible seemed to work, but I am yet to see if it will keep working. As I have stated, this issue is quite elusive.

Comment: Regarding WinActivate, my previous tests indicated that COM objects ignored it, but perhaps I overlooked some detail because upon testing again now it appears that it indeed can be used instead of Documents.Activate. Nevertheless, this issue with activation is a known limitation of COM to manipulate word. See these threads: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=31840 and  https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=45812.

Comment: Yes, you've done some research. But the `.Activate` method on the COM object is different from `WinActivate` which works on the Windows desktop collection itself. In the meantime, as before, I think the Application object has to be `.visible` for any interaction by the desktop (i.e., simulating keystrokes or mouse movements etc.) possibly including the desktop Activation.